# Struct e matriz, como relacionar?

Tags: c, matriz, struct

Eu estou fazendo um código para um trabalho da faculdade e surgiu uma dúvida a cerca de como deve ser feita a atribuição de valores a uma matriz do tipo `struct`.

```
 struct posicao
{
int x;
int y;
};
struct posicao inimigo_val[5][15] = {
{{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1}},
{{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1}},
{{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1}},
{{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1}},
{{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1}},
{{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1},{0,-1}}
};
```

Pensei em fazer a atribuição dessa maneira, estaria correto? Existe algum problema no uso de `struct` com matriz? Existe uma maneira mais prática de atribuir os valores? Lembrando que seriam valores diferentes em cada membro, isso foi apenas um exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, está correto.

Nenhum problema em usar isto, na verdade é bem comum.

Existem várias outras formas de declarar, mas esta parece estar boa. Alguns prefeririam ser explícitos usando os nomes dos membros da estrutura, mas não é fundamental.É gosto de legibilidade (questionável, porque fica mais longo e pode até prejudicar, tudo depende de contexto).

Comment: muito obg, e caso eu queira acessar os valores dessa matriz?

Comment: devo usar inimigo_val[i][j].x? dessa forma?

Comment: Exatamente isto.